# C# InvalidArgument = Value of '2' is not valid for 'index'

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, checkedlistbox

I am new to C# and I have encountered an error stating that: InvalidArgument=Value of '2' is not valid for 'index'.

I want to set the items in checkedlistbox checked if there is a match in listbox.
Can anyone help me with this problem.

This the part of my code where the problems appear.

```
for (int i = 0; i < checklistbox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (checklistbox.Items[i].ToString() == listbox.Items[i].ToString())
     {
        //Check only if they match! 
        checklistbox.SetItemChecked(i, true);
     }
}
```

Comment: probably `listbox.Items` have only 2 elements, and you're trying to access the third one.

Comment: yes it has only 2 elements

Comment: `checklistbox` and `listbox` should have the same number of elements for this to work. And remember c# arrays are zero-based.

Comment: I have another set of code that the elements of the checkedlistbox is 4 while the listbox is 2, yet it still works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use nested for loop. Here is the code.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < listbox.Items.Count; i++)
 {
   for (int j = 0; j < checkedlistbox.Items.Count; j++)
   {
     if (listbox.Items[i].ToString() == checkedlistbox.Items[j].ToString())
     {
       //Check only if they match! 
       checkedlistbox.SetItemChecked(i, true);
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are looping through the count of checklistbox items. So, for example if there are 3 items in that array, and listbox only has 2 items, then on the third loop (when i = 2), you are trying to reference an item in the listbox array that does not exist.

Another way to do it would be like this:

```
foreach (var item in listbox.Items)
        {
            if (Array.Exists(checklistbox.Items, lbitem => lbitem.ToString() == item.ToString()))
            {
               //They match! 
               checklistbox[item].MarkAsChecked()
            }
        }
```

Update: answer updated to add MarkAsChecked() and loop through user inputted values held within checklist array.

Comment: Sorry to say, but this does'nt solve my problem. I want that the items in checkedlistbox to be checked if there is a match in listbox. The flow of my program is that, the user input the elements then it willl be displayed in the listbox, then if the inputted elements match with the predefined elements in checkedlistbox, that elements will be checked. That is why the index of checkedlistbox and listbox does not match.

Comment: Okay, you should probably loop through the users input values (held within listbox) rather than looping through what could be a huge list of items in the checklistbox, by using the syntax in my answer, then when a match is found, there should be a method (function) on checkedListBox class that you call when a match is found. Something like checkedListBox[i].MarkAsChecked()